# How can I use regex to match only one character in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying do precess a list of files

```
file_list = ['.DS_Store', '9', '7', '6', '8', '01', '4', '3', '2', '5']
```

the goal is to find the files whose name has only one character.

I tried this code

```
r = re.compile('[0-9]')
result_list =  list(filter(r.match, file_list))
result_list
```

and got

```
['9', '7', '6', '8', '01', '4', '3', '2', '5']
```

where '01' should not be included.

I made a workaround

```
tmp = []
for i in file_list:
    if len(i)==1:
        tmp.append(i)
tmp
```

and I got

```
['9', '7', '6', '8', '4', '3', '2', '5']
```

this is exactly what I want. Although the method is ugly.

how can I use regex in Python to finish the task?

Comment: Why do you think the method is ugly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = re.compile('^[0-9]$')
```

The `^` matches the beginning of a line and `$` matches the end.

And if you really want it to match *any* character, not just numbers, it should be

```
r = re.compile('^.$')
```

The `.` in the regex is a single-character wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to

```
[ i for i in file_list if len(i)==1]
```

And this method adapts to every case in which file's name has only one character.

Answer (score 1):

Match a string if it's simply any single character appearing at the beginning of the string (`^.`) right before the end of the string (`$`):

```
^.$
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/8xI94J/1)

Your Python then becomes:

```
r = re.compile('^.$')
result_list =  list(filter(r.match, file_list))
```